# CKAN: How to fix error 504 when serving a big file

Tags: ckan

I'm trying to publish a big CSV file in my CKAN 2.8 installation. It publishes fine and I can see the preview in the Data Explorer.

It downloads sucessfuly when I click on the "Download" button, but fails when I try to download it in a converted format like Json, TSV or XML.

Every time I try to download, I get the following error after *30 seconds*:

```
504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.
```

Which configuration must I change to increase this timeout in CKAN 2.8?

Comment: I haven't experienced such an issue but could you try to change your uwsgi config options? There should be parameters for setting up timeouts I guess.

Comment: @anuveyatsu I don't know where to set my uwsgi config options. Can you show me an example of changing it?

Comment: you should have a script that starts your CKAN app, for example, https://github.com/okfn/docker-ckan/blob/master/ckan-base/2.8/setup/start_ckan.sh where you can find uwsgi options

Comment: In the Nginx configuration try removing defaults from proxy_max_temp_file_size and set it to 0. Also since CKAN is running uwsgi behind nginx try and enable caching with proxy_max_temp_file_size.